# Declare single item in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have following grid-item. Here layout is

```
<grid-item v-for="item in layout" :x="item.x" :y="item.y" :w="item.w" :h="item.h" :i="item.i">
    {{item.i}}
</grid-item>
```

Here layout is as following:

```
layout = [
        { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 1, "h": 1, "i": "0" },
        { "x": 1, "y": 0, "w": 1, "h": 1, "i": "1" }
    ];
```

Now I want to change layout as following.

```
layout = {
        pnlProject:  { "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 1, "h": 1, "i": "0" },
        pnlRight: { "x": 1, "y": 0, "w": 1, "h": 1, "i": "1" }
};
```

So previously it was array, Now I will require separate grid item. So what will be my component look like syntactically?

I tried following.

```
<grid-item :x="layout.pnlProject.x" :y="layout.pnlProject.y" :w="layout.pnlProject.w" :h="layout.pnlProject.h" :i="layout.pnlProject.i">
    {{ layout.pnlProject.i }}
</grid-item>
<grid-item :x="layout.pnlRight.x" :y="layout.pnlRight.y" :w="layout.pnlRight.w" :h="layout.pnlRight.h" :i="layout.pnlRight.i">
    {{ layout.pnlRight.i }}
</grid-item>
```

But here, layout.pnlProject & layout.pnlRight are repeated. So it there a way to avoid that. and ability to write in a way of declaring something like **'item'** variable of loop, but without loop?

Comment: It seems the simply way is `<grid-item v-for="item in layout.pnlProject" :x="item.x" :y="item.y" :w="item.w" :h="item.h" :i="item.i">
    {{item.i}}
</grid-item>`

Comment: ok. so itsnt there any other way apart from for loop for syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to have 2 elements, possibly:

```
<grid-item :x="layout.pnlProject.x" :y="layout.pnlProject.y" :w="layout.pnlProject.w" :h="layout.pnlProject.h" :i="layout.pnlProject.i">
    {{ layout.pnlProject.i }}
</grid-item>
<grid-item :x="layout.pnlRight.x" :y="layout.pnlRight.y" :w="layout.pnlRight.w" :h="layout.pnlRight.h" :i="layout.pnlRight.i">
    {{ layout.pnlRight.i }}
</grid-item>
```

If you want to keep the `grid-item` as is (with a loop), you could just get the values from the object:

```
<grid-item v-for="item in layout.values()" :x="item.x" :y="item.y" :w="item.w" :h="item.h" :i="item.i">
  {{ item.i }}
</grid-item>
```

Another option I can think of is to create another component and pass the object as props. Assuming you're using single file components:

```
<template>
  <grid-item :x="data.x" :y="data.y" :w="data.w" :h="data.h" :i="data.i">
    {{ data.i }}
  </grid-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-grid-item'
  props: ['data']
}
</script>
```

And call it like this:

```
<my-grid-item :data="layout.pnlProject" />
<my-grid-item :data="layout.pnlRight" />
```

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention that I had tried this. I updated question.

Comment: ok. will I have to use for loop syntax? isn't there any other option?

Comment: you can either access the object values one by one, or access the values of the layout element (which will give you an array of elements). Not sure which other option you want?

Comment: as I have 2 fixed values. I dont want to loop. so.

Comment: Updated answer's last option looks expensive. I'll go with your loop syntax if no other alternative. ;)

Comment: It's not expensive. Depending on your use-case, you may argue it's over-engineered, but if you want to create a re-usable component it's definitely the best one to avoid code duplication